# Read Integer Array 2nd time

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, int

I use this to read an array of ints:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     scanf("%d", ptr1);
     ptr1++;
 }
```

after declaring a pointer `int *ptr1` and `ptr1=&arr[0]`. I am making a game so in a `while` loop I have to read this array every time it loops. For example if the first time the array is `arr=[0,1,1,2]` I want it to change the next time I read it. How can I accomplish that without the array to remain the same?

Comment: What is the question? does it remain the same? and 2 things, `int *ptr = &arr[0];` is just `int *ptr = arr;` and `scanf("%d", &ptr1[i]);` would be simpler to write. Also, ignoring the return value from `scanf()` is by far the most common bad thing "_programmers_" do, specially books and tutorials.

Comment: Yes the array remains the same.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Please post a reproducible sample as a minimum. Or your real code.

Comment: @iharob Props for mentioning the return value of `scanf`... Unfortunately, it's commonly overlooked even after you've warned people for a first, second (and possibly even third?) time. Unfortunately it isn't until they realise that *it is possible to enter non-numeric data when `scanf` is told to expect numeric data* that they try all sorts of stupid things <strike>like using `isdigit` on an `int` value read by `scanf`</strike>... If only they'd try *checking the return value*, first!

Comment: did you used `malloc` for `ptr1`? of left it as a static?